# Problems using InfraRecorder to back up ISOs of certain CDs

Tags: backup, iso-image, compact-disc

I've gotten into the habit of backing up my CDs as ISO files, just in case the discs should be damaged, lost, or destroyed. Using InfraRecorder, the process is pretty painless.

Unfortunately, I have run into at least two discs that don't back up. I get the error message:

> Can't read source disc. Retrying from sector 252270

Sometimes this will appear repeatedly. One of the discs is my retail copy of *Star Trek: Armada II*; the other is disc one of *DOOM 3*. Both discs run flawlessly when I put them in the drive and let Windows AutoPlay them.

*Armada II* appears as two tracks (one data, one audio) in InfraRecorder, and the error happens at the approximate track boundary. *DOOM 3*'s first disc, however, fails much sooner (around sector 990) and appears as one solid data track.

Am I simply using the wrong tools for this job? InfraRecorder is a nice free tool that I can run from my flash drive and use for most tasks of this type, but it does seem to have trouble with certain things.

Ideally I'd like to hear about any workarounds people have found for this issue, but if I must switch tools I'm open to it (preferably other free tools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ISO file format isn't really designed to hold both audio and data tracks, that's probably what you're running into with *Star Trek II: Armada*.  I'm not sure about *Doom 3*, it's possible it might have some form of DRM on it.

For games in particular, just using InfraRecorder by itself isn't going to be the best tool for the job.  The big problem you'll have is copy-protected games.  You'll need a tool that can handle creating images of those that will pass the DRM schemes on the disc.  Products like Alcohol 52% and Alcohol 120%, CloneCD, and Daemon Tools (among others) are designed to handle tasks like making images of copy protected discs, mounting them as virtual drives, and burning them to blank media.